# How should I check for EOF in Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell

I have a Ruby script (1.8.7) that sets up its own interactive shell for running specific commands.
I want to be able to exit when a user presses CTRL+D (mac/linux).  The script just sits in a loop and uses Readline to read user input.  I understand that CTRL+D sends the EOF control character but how do I test for this in Ruby?  It doesn't seem to be included in the lists of standard unix signals and since technically it isn't a character, I'm guessing normal string comparison on the line won't work either.

Any ideas / pointers / suggestions would be much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: It is not included in the list of standard unix signals, because it isn't a signal. As you already correctly said yourself, it is more of a character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/readline/rdoc/Readline.html#readline-method):

> **readline(prompt = "", add_hist = false)**
>
> (…) Returns nil when the inputted line is empty and user inputs EOF (Presses ^D on UNIX).

Example:

```
require "readline"
while buf = Readline.readline("> ", true)
  p buf
end
puts "EOF received, exiting"
```